# Unable to take screenshots, "Couldn't save screenshot, storage may be in use" error

Tags: applications, screenshots

I am just trying to take a screenshot of my starbucks rewards card, so I can print it out. Apparently a lot of apps like netflix, hulu, and starbucks recently have been restricting screenshots for obvious reasons. All the screenshot tools I try give me an error (I have root access). The error is always " Couldn't save screenshot. Storage may be in use".

Comment: Related: [How can I take on-device screenshots of “secure” apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/138778/1465)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might probably due to *permissions error* in KitKat (and Lollipop) running Android phones.

♦ *Layman Solution :*
The most common way is to reboot your android phone and try taking the screenshot.
If it doesn't cut it, try going into safe mode and come back to normal mode back.

♦ *Professional Solution :*
Wipe dalvik cache in recovery mode.

♦ *For Xiaomi users :*
Create a folder called Screenshots in `/sdcard/DCIM/`
Note: MIUI saves screenshots in `/sdcard/DCIM/screenshots/`

Answer (score 1):

1. Install “ES File Explorer” from the Play Store. Open it and navigate to internal SD card storage
2. Delete “Pictures” folder
3. Create a  new “Pictures” folder and open it and make “Screenshots” folder inside “Pictures" folder

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get your screenshots up and running:

1. Open file manager
2. Look for PICTURES folder.
3. Rename it to PICTURES2 or something

That's it. Screenshots up and running.

Now why is that? That's because the folder PICTURES is actually supposed to be Pictures. When you try to capture a screenshot, the screenshot app looks for a folder called Pictures but since it doesn’t exist, it tries to create it. But File Manager doesn’t differentiate between Pictures and PICTURES. Hence the error. When you do the rename and capture a screenshot you can actually see a folder called Pictures created. Now you can move the data from PICTURES2 to Pictures (only the important one and without deleting any existing content in Pictures). It is safe to delete the PICTURES2 folder after this.

(This solution is tried by me on One Plus 2 and it worked.)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have tried other solution but hasn't worked , try this: unmount your SD card on setting and then mount your SD card back. This actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem
When choosing to store on phone it works 
While when use to store on sd card give the same error
I tried all the solutions but didn't work
But at last i tried this and worked 
Creat a folder in the sd card and name it Pictures
Then create another folder inside it and name it Screenshots

Answer (score -1):

Thats not any type of app restriction. Its a bug in your software part.

*You can try this->*

Go to `/sdcard/Pictures/screenshots` and rename `screenshots` to something else. Restart and retry taking the screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

have you lot  actually looked to see if your phone HAS taken a screenshot? because I get that error message but the screenshot has been taken and IS saved, even though it says it can't save it.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an Answer. You need to earn sufficient reputations to be able to comment on other's post.

Answer (score -1):

I went into file manager and moved everything from the phone to the SD card and it solved the problem.