# cannot take screenshots in a banking app

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, security, privacy, screenshots

I have an unlocked Android 6.0.1 device, and I've installed a couple of banking apps.

For obvious security and paper trail reasons, I'd like to take some screenshots of my interaction with my bank.  However, somehow the low-volume+power buttons no longer takes any screenshots whilst in either of the banking apps.

Why?  How do I disable such a nuisance?

Comment: Also duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/138778/131553

Comment: Please take the trouble of searching before posting

Comment: @beeshyams Now that you mentioned it, shame that I didn't before answering either...

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of [`FLAG_SECURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE). The reason is obviously again security - other apps can either leverage the native screenshot API, or just read your captured results from storage to potentially obtain sensitive info.

If you're already into Xposed framework, then there are a bunch of modules that will disable the check for the flag system-wide, such as [this one](http://repo.xposed.info/module/fi.veetipaananen.android.disableflagsecure).

As @iBug already pointed out, always exercise extreme caution when working around security measures, especially when a 3rd-party app is involved.

Comment: thanks!  it's sad that such features get introduced; haven't had this problem just a few releases ago

Comment: It's to stop malicious software being able to capture sensitive data from your screen

Answer (score 0):

You can't take a screenshot in the regular way in such apps. Android allows foreground apps to prevent you from taking screenshots.
However you can still 'force take' screenshots with 3rd party apps, most of which requires root. As for myself I don't recommend this, as 3rd party apps can lead to even greater security & privacy unless you have a trusted app.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy Yan said, it is caused by FLAG_SECURE that developer set as window attribute. Without root you can't take screenshot. But you can still take picture with camera on another phone ;-) Old school solution but it will definetely work.