# How can apps hide their content on recent apps screen?

Tags: android-13, recents-screen

Does anybody know what exactly a functionality is in recent apps, means I have seen in Android 13 that when any of the payment apps is in the recent apps screen, then one blank screen is there along with a closed eye icon and a text showing "App content hidden", irrespective of the app lock, means it is locked or not.

[image]

If anybody knows what exactly it is in Android, then please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, you might want to try our sister site [so].

Comment: That said, I'd assume it's the `FLAG_SECURE`, similar to [How can I take on-device screenshots of "secure" apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138778/44325)

Comment: Or possibly using [FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS).